# Runtime Error: SwiftUI: No image named '' found in asset catalog for main bundle

Tags: swiftui

This is the error I'm getting:

[image]

```
runtime: SwiftUI: No image named '' found in asset catalog for main bundle (/Users/yun/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/623B1BB3-5C34-4311-AA41-86C42FE27439/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/8E87B349-36CA-41B8-A34C-02BBB2F00472/Travel.app)
```

The image doesn't have a name, just `''`, so I can't find the cause of the error.

```
//  AppDelegate.swift <br>
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate { <-- this is the break point...
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The error that you are receiving means that somewhere in your code you are initiating an `Image("some name")` and passing in an empty string "".

Try a search for `Image(` in Xcode and see if there are any Image views maybe, with default values that are blank.

Also, if you really want to debug this issue, and find the missing image name among potentially thousands of lines of code, you can try out this nifty extension:

```
#if DEBUG
    extension Image {
        init(_ str: String) {
            guard let img = UIImage(named: str) else {
                print(str)
                fatalError("found an image that doesn't exist, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63006278/11161266")
            }
            self.init(uiImage: img)
        }
        init(systemName sys: String) {
            guard let img = UIImage(systemName: sys) else {
                print(sys)
                fatalError("found an image that doesn't exist, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63006278/11161266")
            }
            self.init(uiImage: img)
        }
        
    }
#endif
```

It will force a crash when it finds a missing image, and you can navigate directly to the line of code that caused it:

[image: image describing how to find the line]

Alternatively, you could easily modify the above extension to provide a default value to all your empty images:

```
extension Image {
    init(_ str: String) {
        self.init(uiImage: 
             UIImage(named: str) ?? UIImage(named: "Some default image")!
        )
    }
}
```